# Mutating new columns based on common string using existing columns

Tags: r, dplyr

Sample data:

```
    X_5   X_1     Y alpha_5 alpha_1 beta_5 beta_1
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1  0.21  0.02  0.61   10      5       3      0.01
2  0.01  0.02  0.37    0.4    0.01    0.8    0.5 
3  0.02  0.03  0.55    0.01   0.01    0.3    0.99
4  0.04  0.05  0.29    0.01   0.005   0.03   0.55
5  0.11  0.1  -0.08    0.22   0.015   0.01   0.01
6  0.22  0.21 -0.08    0.02   0.03    0.01   0.01
```

I have a dataset which has columns of some variable of interest, say alpha, beta, and so on. I also have this saved as a character vector. I want to be able to mutate new columns based on these variable names, suffixed with an identifier, using the existing columns in the dataset as part of some transformation, like this:

```
df %>% mutate(
  alpha_new = ((alpha_5-alpha_1) / (X_5-X_1) * Y),
  beta_new = ((beta_5-beta_1) / (X_5-X_1) * Y)
)

    X_5   X_1     Y alpha_5 alpha_1 beta_5 beta_1 alpha_new beta_new
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1  0.21  0.02  0.61   10      5       3      0.01   16.1        9.60
2  0.01  0.02  0.37    0.4    0.01    0.8    0.5   -14.4      -11.1 
3  0.02  0.03  0.55    0.01   0.01    0.3    0.99    0         38.0 
4  0.04  0.05  0.29    0.01   0.005   0.03   0.55   -0.145     15.1 
5  0.11  0.1  -0.08    0.22   0.015   0.01   0.01   -1.64       0   
6  0.22  0.21 -0.08    0.02   0.03    0.01   0.01    0.0800     0
```

In my real data I have many more columns like this and I'm struggling to implement this in a "tidy" way which isn't hardcoded, what's the best practice for my situation?

Sample code:

```
  structure(
  list(
    X_5 = c(0.21, 0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.11, 0.22),
    X_1 = c(0.02,
            0.02, 0.03, 0.05, 0.10, 0.21),
    Y = c(0.61, 0.37, 0.55, 0.29, -0.08, -0.08),
    alpha_5 = c(10, 0.4, 0.01, 0.01, 0.22, 0.02),
    alpha_1 = c(5, 0.01, 0.01, 0.005, 0.015, 0.03),
    beta_5 = c(3, 0.8, 0.3, 0.03, 0.01, 0.01),
    beta_1 = c(0.01, 0.5, 0.99, 0.55, 0.01, 0.01)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -6L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
) -> df

variable_of_interest <- c("alpha", "beta")
```

Comment: Do you want to do it two by two? say there is alpha_2, do you want all combinations, only adjacent columns?

Comment: could you post a list of your column names?

Comment: @TarJae they're identical to the columns in the sample dataframe but I replaced my variables of interest with alpha, beta etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way to approach this with dynamic creation of columns. With `map_dfc` from `purrr` you can column-bind new results, creating new column names with bang-bang on left hand side of `:=` operator, and using .data to access column values on right hand side.

```
library(tidyverse)

bind_cols(
  df,
  map_dfc(
    variable_of_interest,
    ~ transmute(df, !!paste0(.x, '_new') := 
                  (.data[[paste0(.x, '_5')]] - .data[[paste0(.x, '_1')]]) /
                  (X_5 - X_1) * Y)
  )
)
```

**Output**

```
   X_5  X_1     Y alpha_5 alpha_1 beta_5 beta_1 alpha_new   beta_new
1 0.21 0.02  0.61   10.00   5.000   3.00   0.01  16.05263   9.599474
2 0.01 0.02  0.37    0.40   0.010   0.80   0.50 -14.43000 -11.100000
3 0.02 0.03  0.55    0.01   0.010   0.30   0.99   0.00000  37.950000
4 0.04 0.05  0.29    0.01   0.005   0.03   0.55  -0.14500  15.080000
5 0.11 0.10 -0.08    0.22   0.015   0.01   0.01  -1.64000   0.000000
6 0.22 0.21 -0.08    0.02   0.030   0.01   0.01   0.08000   0.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to pivot the data first

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# your data
df <- structure(list(X_5 = c(0.21, 0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.11, 0.22), X_1 = c(0.02, 
0.02, 0.03, 0.05, 0.1, 0.21), Y = c(0.61, 0.37, 0.55, 0.29, -0.08, 
-0.08), alpha_5 = c(10, 0.4, 0.01, 0.01, 0.22, 0.02), alpha_1 = c(5, 
0.01, 0.01, 0.005, 0.015, 0.03), beta_5 = c(3, 0.8, 0.3, 0.03, 
0.01, 0.01), beta_1 = c(0.01, 0.5, 0.99, 0.55, 0.01, 0.01)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

```
df <- df |> mutate(id = 1:n()) |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(id, Y, X_5, X_1), 
               names_to = c("name", ".value"),  names_sep="_") |> 
  mutate(new= (`5` - `1`) / (X_5 - X_1) * Y) |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id, names_from = "name", values_from = c(`5`,`1`, `new`), 
               names_glue = "{name}_{.value}", values_fn = sum)

df
#> # A tibble: 6 × 7
#>      id alpha_5 beta_5 alpha_1 beta_1 alpha_new beta_new
#>   <int>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     1   10      3      5       0.01   16.1        9.60
#> 2     2    0.4    0.8    0.01    0.5   -14.4      -11.1 
#> 3     3    0.01   0.3    0.01    0.99    0         38.0 
#> 4     4    0.01   0.03   0.005   0.55   -0.145     15.1 
#> 5     5    0.22   0.01   0.015   0.01   -1.64       0   
#> 6     6    0.02   0.01   0.03    0.01    0.0800     0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Note: if you want to add X_5 and X_1 in the output use `id_cols = c(id, X_5, X_1)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your data to create a bit more complicated situation. My hope is that this is close to your real situation. The condition in this idea is that two columns that you wanna pair up stay next to each other. The first job is to collect column names that begin with small letters. Next job is to create a data frame. Here I keep the column names in odd positions
in `target` in the first column, and ones in even positions in the second column. I was thinking in the same line of Ben; I used `map2_dfc` to create an output data frame. In this function, I replaced all small letters with `X` so that I could specify two column names in the original data (i.e., ones starting with `X`). Then, I did the calculation as you specified. Finally, I created a column name for outcome in the loop. If you want to add the result to the original data, you can run the final line with `cbind`.

```
grep(x = names(df), pattern = "[[:lower:]]+_[0-9]+", value = TRUE) -> target

tibble(first_element = target[c(TRUE, FALSE)],
       second_element = target[c(FALSE, TRUE)]) -> mydf

map2_dfc(.x = mydf$first_element,
         .y = mydf$second_element,
         .f = function(x, y) {
       
           sub(x = x, pattern = "[[:lower:]]+", replacement = "X") -> foo1
           sub(x = y, pattern = "[[:lower:]]+", replacement = "X") -> foo2
       
           outcome <- ((df[x] - df[y]) / (df[foo1] - df[foo2]) * df["Y"])
           names(outcome) <- paste(x,
                                   sub(x = y, pattern = "[[:lower:]]+", replacement = ""),
                                   sep = "")
           return(outcome)
       
         }) -> result

cbind(df, result)

#  alpha_5_1 alpha_2_6   beta_5_1 beta_3_4
#1  16.05263   0.10736   9.599474  0.27145
#2 -14.43000   0.10730 -11.100000  0.28564
#3   0.00000   0.28710  37.950000  0.50820
#4  -0.14500   0.21576  15.080000  0.64206
#5  -1.64000  -0.06416   0.000000 -0.61352
#6   0.08000  -0.08480   0.000000 -0.25400
```

**DATA**

```
structure(list(
X_5 = c(0.21, 0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.11, 0.22),
X_1 = c(0.02,0.02, 0.03, 0.05, 0.10, 0.21),
X_2 = 1:6,
X_6 = 6:11,
X_3 = 21:26,
X_4 = 31:36,
Y = c(0.61, 0.37, 0.55, 0.29, -0.08, -0.08),
alpha_5 = c(10, 0.4, 0.01, 0.01, 0.22, 0.02),
alpha_1 = c(5, 0.01, 0.01, 0.005, 0.015, 0.03),
alpha_2 = c(0.12, 0.55, 0.39, 0.28, 0.99, 0.7),
alpha_6 = 1:6,
beta_5 = c(3, 0.8, 0.3, 0.03, 0.01, 0.01),
beta_1 = c(0.01, 0.5, 0.99, 0.55, 0.01, 0.01),
beta_3 = c(0.55, 0.28, 0.76, 0.86, 0.31, 0.25),
beta_4 = c(5, 8, 10, 23, 77, 32)),
row.names = c(NA, -6L),
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) -> df
```